# Cant show images with html source tag in Wordpress twig

Tags: wordpress, image, twig

I am building a Wordpress page with the theme Lumberjack that uses Timber and Twig. On my local machine, the images are showing without problem but when I moved the site to WP Engine the images dont show. The picutre and source tags sizes are 0. Here is the HTML:

```
<picture>
<source srcset="http://myurl" type="image/jpeg">
<img class="card__image" loading="lazy" src="https://myurl" alt="" role="presentation">
</picture>
```

As I said it works locally and it is the exact same code locally and on WPE. I have also tried the url in the browser and it displays the image. The image should show a placeholder if the featured image is empty, which it doesnt either.

My twig looks like this:

```
{% if card.thumbnail|length > 0  %}
    <a href="{{ card.link }}" title="{{ card.title }}">
    <picture>
        <source srcset="{{ card.thumbnail.src('card')|tojpg }}" type="image/jpeg">
        <img class="card__image" loading="lazy" src="{{ card.thumbnail.src('card')|tojpg }}" alt="{{ card.thumbnail.alt }}" role="presentation"/>
    </picture> 
    </a>
{% else  %}
    <a href="{{ card.link }}" class="card__image-placeholder" title="{{ card.title }}"></a>
{% endif %}
```

Does anyone know why the image is not displayed on WP Engine?

Comment: Is the wordpress page hosted with SSL and are you by chance delivering the images over `http://`´  instead of `https://´?

Comment: Yes I saw now that that is the problem.. I made a search and replace in the database and that solved it. Thanks!